# Choosing when to load the second form (auth server)

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm having problems allowing my form to load the second form. I'm trying to set up an auth server: On a form called Form2. And program it to if the auth code is correct, to go to the MainForm. So I want it to after displaying "auth code disabled" to close Form2 and load MainForm. Here's the code for Form2 (the form with the authentication server code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace BBP
{
public partial class auth : Form
{

public static String Auth = null;
public static String Authcode = null;
public static String ip = null;
public auth()
{

InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
{
Auth = textBox1.Text;
if (Auth == (""))
{
MessageBox.Show("Enter Auth Code");
}

else
if (webBrowser3.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains(textBox1.Text))
MessageBox.Show("Auth Code Disabled");
else
if (webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains(textBox1.Text))
{
this.Hide();
 Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 f2.ShowDialog();
Application.Exit();
}
  else

 if (webBrowser2.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains(textBox1.Text))
 {

 this.Hide();
 Form2 f3 = new Form2();
 f3.ShowDialog();


Application.Exit();
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Invalid Auth Code");
}

}}

 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)                       
 {

 }


 }
 }
```

Comment: Not clear. You want to load your "auth" form as a splash screen?

Comment: No, I want my auth form to load. And after it loads, after displaying the message box "auth code disabled" to load the second form (MainForm)

Comment: okay and? What is it that your program is doing instead of what it is that you want it to do?

Comment: After saying "auth code disabled" It doesn't load the second form

Comment: Of course not, there is no code there to show the other form. Did you debug your code? Does webbrowser1 and 2 contain the text?

Answer (score 0):

Close the 'Application.Exit()' line and try again. You can NOT open a form after say : exit from the application.

Comment: I tried that. And after the "auth disabled" message comes, it doesn't prompt me to the second form (MainForm)

Comment: you are using a message box to say "auth disabled" but after this line there is no code to prompt you a new form. After the line "MessageBox.Show("Auth Code Disabled");", there is nothing to do. Look your code again, carefully.